# How to upload original JPG file by jQuery File Upload and disable the thumbnail creating?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I use the jQuery File Upload and it works great. However I find that the uploaded JPGs are compressed and there is an option in UploadHandler.php :

```
case 'jpg':
case 'jpeg':
                $src_func = 'imagecreatefromjpeg';
                $write_func = 'imagejpeg';
                $image_quality = isset($options['jpeg_quality']) ?
                    $options['jpeg_quality'] : 75;
                break;
```

I want to know is there a way to let it upload original JPG file without compressing, and disable the thumbnail creating?

Comment: update the index `jpeg_quality` of the `$options` array to `100` and set the default value from `75` to `100` would keep the original quality of the image

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it will compress the data still even set 100. If there is a way to upload it directly and don't let the program process images?